# Orchard CMS Theme Images Not Showing Up

Tags: orchardcms

I'm using the correct helper call to get the URL for an image in my theme:

```
@Url.Content(Html.ThemePath(WorkContext.CurrentTheme, "/Content/Images/my-image.png")
```

...and I know the image is there and is readable. Yet it's not showing up when I try to browse to it! Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6):

From the docs (http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Anatomy-of-a-theme):

> *To enable files to be served, each of the folders that contains static files such as style sheets, images, or JavaScript code should contain a web.config file that contains the following content*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <!-- iis6 - for any request in this location,
           return via managed static file handler -->
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Script,Read">
      <!-- iis7 - for any request to a file exists on disk,
           return it via native http module.
           accessPolicy 'Script' is to allow for a managed 404 page. -->
      <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule"
           preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="File"
           requireAccess="Read" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```